# What to use instead of Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent

Tags: android, google-play-games

As you can see in [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html) ***Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent*** is getting deprecated and my question is what to use instead to search and pick players. I'm building small 2D multiplayer game and I'm stuck on it. I would like to use newest way to do it. Also if I would have to stay with deprecated one I don't know how to build my own UI for it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should show your work first

Comment: I'm trying to create a room after clicking "Create game" (I'm already signed in). It will open lobby activity with all players listed and with button "Search" - after clicking it I would like to list players that you can send invite to

Comment: [Blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html) is quite confusing since main update is that Google+ is no longer integrated and mentioned about using Google Sign-In API for authentication.

Comment: Also, referring to [Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer), `getSelectOpponentsIntent()` method can still be used to launch the default player picker UI in handling [invite players options](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#invite_players_option). Just note that you also have to implement [sign-in in your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin).

Comment: The most important part is in the end. It is saying that method I want to use is getting deprecated

Comment: @Jakub Jendryka Did you find a solution for that?